# show result of datalist in popup asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a Datalist that works well and data shows in the page , but i want when user click on the **button** the result of datalist shows in a popup java script.
this is my code :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
<table class="auto-style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2" rowspan="3"><asp:Image ID="imgEmp" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImagesC", "{0}") %>' style="padding-left:40px"/></td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <b><u><%# Eval("NameC") %></td></u></b>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ti</td>
        <td>GB</td>
        <td>Gh</td>
        <td>Eimeni</td>
        <td>rotbe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("Ti")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("GB")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Gh")%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
         </ItemTemplate>
```

I didn't put here behind codes as there are a lot of codes, but if it is necessary let me know to put them too.
thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code you have written so far?

Comment: actually i don't have any idea how it can be done, i already tried with some samples but without successful

Answer (score 0):

This is general idea how to do this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm" /><%--required by UpdatePanel --%>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPopup" UpdateMode="Conditional">
//update
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPopup" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
//end update
    <ContentTemplate>
       <%-- Use proper CSS to display it as a popup --%>
       <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" CssClass="my-popup" runat="server" Visible="false">
          <asp:DataList ID="dlPop" runat="server">
          </asp:DataList>
       </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" OnClick="btnPopup_Click" />

//.cs
protected void btnPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //BindDataList();
    pnlPopup.Visible = true;
    upPopup.Update();
}
```

`UpdatePanel` uses `AJAX` request so no additional JS required.

Comment: When you said "proper CSS" , you mean using CSS like follow ?: https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I added CSS and added my code between <DIV> tag and added relevant ID and Class to my ASP button, but nothing happened when I clicked on button.